# zoom not working on 3d plot in matplotlib on a mac

Tags: macos, matplotlib, 3d, zooming

There are a few questions regarding this issue but they are quite old.  Moreover, the solutions that are listed do not seem to work for me, so I'm wondering if this is a new issue.  The problem is that I am unable to interactively zoom when viewing a 3d plot in matplotlib.  I have tried all possible (I think) combinations of right/left/center clicks and drags, including using the pan and zoom buttons on the interactive plot.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  I am using a macbook pro.

Comment: Note that I *can* resize the entire image, but I want to zoom in instead.

Comment: Zooming in 3D is performed via clicking the right mousebutton within the axes, holding it and moving the mouse towards/away from the center of the plot. If this doesn't work for you, you might want to share the system you are using, versions, backend, how you installed matplotlib (is it used in a framework?),etc. If all those information are available and clear steps of reproduction, you may also create an issue at the github issue tracker.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I'm using a macbook pro so it has a trackpad, but I've tried every combination of clicking I can think of (cnt-click, opt-click, cmd-click, cmd-shift-click, etc.)  I am running MacOS 10.12.6.  I installed python using anaconda (3.5.1.0 I believe) and this included matplotlib.  Sorry, but that's about all I know.

Comment: Okay, so this is going to sound really weird, but this morning I was actually able to zoom my 3d plot.  I was simply trying to rotate the image, but it actually zoomed.  As long as I didn't let go of my click, I was able to zoom in and out, but as soon as I released the click, the zooming was gone.   As far as I know, all I did was a regular (left-button) click, but clearly I must have done something differently.  Not exactly sure what I did, but I have not been able to get it to zoom again.  This is so weird!  Has anyone else noticed any kind of weird behavior like this?

Comment: I just got it to happen again, but I am still at a loss as to exactly how I did it.  The one thing I now for sure is that there were no keys being pressed.  It seemed to coincide with having multiple fingers on the trackpad, but I have not been able to reproduce it.  As near as I can tell, I used by left thumb to click near the bottom of the trackpad and then had two index fingers on the trackpad.  However, it does not appear to be a click-pinch maneuver.  I'll continue to experiment to see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling and testing, I think I have a solution to this problem.  It appears you need to touch three fingers to the touchpad and (left) click.  At that point, you need to remove one finger (while holding the click); moving the other finger up or down (not left or right) then leads to zooming.  Very strange behavior, but at least I now know how to zoom a 3d figure.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS Sierra with MacOSX backend for matplotlib's plots, holding down `control` and dragging with the trackpad also seems to work, and is much easier.